# Calling lambda functions with iteration over a numpy array of shape `(n,)`

Tags: python, numpy

Let's define a function f such that `f = lambda x1,x2, ... , xn: x1 + x2` and an numpy array `a = np.array([a1,a2, ... , an])` of length `n`. How can I apply f using as arguments the components of `a` by iterating over every element of it?

Notice that I don't want to apply `f` this way: `y = f(a[0], .... a[n])` but using a `for` loop (something like this: `y = lambda(u for u in a)`).

Comment: Do you want to do `f(*a)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [splat](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) unpack trick:

```
>>> a = np.array(['hello ', 'world', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah'])
>>> f = lambda *args: args[0] + args[1]
>>> f(*a)
'hello world'
```